# Add encoding to output GridView to Word

Tags: .net, vb.net

Using the following code I am outputting a GridView to Microsoft Word (via HTML)

```
Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" & CountryName & ".doc")
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word "
    Dim sw As StringWriter = New StringWriter()
    Dim hw As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
    gridview1.AllowPaging = False
    gridview1.DataBind()
    gridview1.RenderControl(hw)
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString())
    Response.Flush()
    Response.[End]()
```

But as it contains characters such as: `É` it is changing it to `Ã‰`

Is this an encoding issue? If so, how can I change the encoding so it will support these characters?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yeah sorry i accidentally left it in whilst was trying to figure it out! Thanks for spotting

Comment: If you open the resulting file in a text editor which shows the encoding (I use EditPad), does the file look correct, and does it tell you what encoding it's using? Otherwise, if you open the file in a hex editor, is there a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) present?

Comment: The only thing it suggests is "<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
" but i dont think this is correct?

Comment: You're right, you don't want that in there. Now you need to find out where it is getting added. I suspect that you are using Web Forms, and that by the time it gets to the code you showed it has already output some data to the response and it is too late to rescind it. The easy way to keep it clean is to use an ashx handler to serve the file instead of an aspx page. [Creating HTTP Handlers](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/ASP.NET/0180__Development/CreatingHTTPHandlers.htm) should set you on the right path.